# Command Line Args in pascal

Tags: command-line-arguments, pascal, delphi

I am new in pascal I have a program which gives result ....
I need to pass command line input in in given variable ip1 and ip2.
Its can be achieved by ParamStr[1] but it doesn't work.

```
  program main;
      var 
        output : integer;
      var 
        ip1 : integer;
      var 
        ip2 : integer;
    
    function add(input1,input2:integer) : integer;
       var
       result: integer;
    begin
       if (input1 > input2) then
          result := input1
       else
          result := input2;
       add := result;
    end;
    
    begin
      ip1 := 2533;**{ command line input}**
      ip2 := 555;**{ command line input}**
    
      output := add(ip1,ip2);
      writeln( ' output : ', output );
    end.K
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `its not works`? Are you having trouble converting the ParamStr values to integer, or what?

Comment: Your function `add` should be called `max` because it does not add the arguments but returns the maximum.

Comment: Hello all, Its Not matter what my function name my problem is how can i pass ip1 and ip2 value using command line. is there any function like args or argv in C or something else....
.pls help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answer says, you use `ParamCount` and `ParamStr` to access command line parameters.

`ParamCount` returns the number of parameters passed on the command line, so you should check it first to see if you've received enough information.

`ParamStr` allows you to access each of the parameters passed. `ParamStr(0)` always gives you the full name of the executing program (including the path). Additional parameters are retrieved using the ordinal order in which they were passed, with `ParamStr(1)` being the first, and `ParamStr(ParamCount)` being the last. Each value received using `ParamStr` is a string value, and therefore has to be converted into the appropriate type before you can use it.

Here's a working example (pretty trivial, and all error checking omitted - you should, for instance, protect the code using `StrToInt` to handle errors if something is provided that won't convert to an integer).

```
program TestParams;

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  Input1, Input2, Output: Integer;

begin
  if ParamCount > 1 then
  begin
    Input1 := StrToInt(ParamStr(1));
    Input2 := StrToInt(ParamStr(2));
    Output := Input1 + Input2;
    WriteLn(Format('%d + %d = %d', [Input1, Input2, Output]));
  end
  else
  begin
    WriteLn('Syntax: ', ParamStr(0));  { Just to demonstrate ParamStr(0) }
    WriteLn('There are two parameters required. You provided ', ParamCount);
  end;
  WriteLn('Press ENTER to exit...');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Calling it without parameters (or only one) displays the following:

```
C:\Temp>TestParams
Syntax: C:\Temp\TestParams.exe
There are two parameters required. You provided 0
Press ENTER to exit...

C:\Temp>TestParams 2
Syntax: C:\Temp>TestParams.exe 2
There are two parameters required. You provided 1
Press ENTER to exit...
```

Calling it with two parameters displays

```
C:\Temp\TestParams 2 2
2 + 2 = 4
Press ENTER to exit...
```

Comment: Facing this error...!!!  

 Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.2 [2013/02/16] for x86_64
    Copyright (c) 1993-2012 by Florian Klaempfl and others
    main.pas(22,22) Error: Identifier not found "StrToInt"
    main.pas(23,22) Error: Identifier not found "StrToInt"
    main.pas(30) Fatal: There were 2 errors compiling module, stopping
    Fatal: Compilation aborted
    Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source file to be compiled).

Is there any pascal version error....?

Comment: You need to add `SysUtils` to your uses clause, just like mine does.

Comment: I'd certainly like to hear from the downvoter what the reason was for doing so, so I can improve my answer by addressing the deficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between a string and an integer.

To convert betwwen an integer such as `123` and the string of characters `1` `2` `3` you need to use a function. `strtoint` is one such function, converting a string to an integer. `inttostr` is another, converting from an integer to a string.

The command-line data is supplied via paramstr(n) as a string.

```
intvar := strtoint(paramstr(n));
```

assigns the value of the string to the integer variable `intvar`.

Whereas `writeln` has facilities to convert an integer argument to a formatted string, the way you have used it is attempting to output a string, so you need to convert the integer `output` to a string.

```
writeln(' output : ', inttostr(output) );
```

should do that very nicely.

---

```
var
  x : string;
  pcnt : integer;

begin
  writeln('Parameter count=',inttostr(paramcount));
  for pcnt := 1 to paramcount do
    writeln('Parameter ',pcnt, ' of ',paramcount,' = ',paramstr(pcnt));
  readln(x);
end.
```

should display the parameter list.

Indeed it is the case that the `writeln` procedure will recognise the variable type and take steps to format the value appropriately as a string, as has arrogantly been pointed out.

The issue to me is the difference between a string and an integer. `paramstr` returns a string which must be converted to an integer. After more than forty years' experience in Pascal, it's my opinion that it's better for a beginner to go through the exercise of converting each way and then use the conversion facility inbuilt in `writeln`.

First walk, then run. You first need to understand the steps in the procedure. Then you can start using the shortcuts - once you've mastered the basics.

Comment: Can you give me example how can  use ParamStr and paramCount using command line in above mention example....its very helpful.